# MSBuild 4.0 property functions cannot access properties inside of them

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0

Is it a limitation of MSBuild 4.0 property functions that I cannot access a property from inside of one?

Here is an example that works just fine:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PartialConnection>$(TargetConnectionString.Substring( 0 + 12))</PartialConnection>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here is another example that doe snot work.  (I replace the `0` with another property)

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LocationOfDataSource>$(TargetConnectionString.IndexOf("Data Source="))</LocationOfDataSource>
</PropertyGroup>
<Message Importance="high" Text="Location is = $(LocationOfDataSource)"/>
<PropertyGroup>
  <PartialConnection>$(TargetConnectionString.Substring( $(LocationOfDataSource) + 12))</PartialConnection>
</PropertyGroup>
```

this outputs

> Location is = 0
>   Error MSB4184: The expression ""Data Source=MySQLServer;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False".Substring(0 + 12)" cannot be evaluated. Input string was not in a correct format.

I took the output and plugged into a console app and it works just fine.  I have tried several variations and I they always fail when I put a property inside a property function.  (I even tried access the same property twice in a my property function and that failed too.)

Do property functions not support accessing properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my issue was assuming that math came for free.

I needed to do this kind of thing:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LocationOfDataSource>$(TargetConnectionString.IndexOf("Data Source="))</LocationOfDataSource>
  <LenthOfDataSourceString>12</LenthOfDataSourceString>
  <LocationOfEndOfDataSourceString>$([MSBuild]::Add($(LocationOfDataSource), $(LenthOfDataSourceString)))</LocationOfEndOfDataSourceString>
  <PartialConnectionString>$(TargetConnectionString.Substring($(LocationOfEndOfDataSourceString)))</PartialConnectionString>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that I am adding using `Add($(Property), $(Property))` in this version. `Add` is one of the built-in [MSBuild Property Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022#msbuild-property-functions) (since MSBuild 4).

It seems to be working now.

Comment: Beat me to it : was just about to post it! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx

Comment: Mark your answer as the answer to your question, please.